# React Native -- How do you register advanced programs (exports.examples) for loading?

Tags: javascript, webview, react-native

I'm learning and honing my skills on react-native.  I've been playing a lot with some of the simple examples starting with the very basic AwesomeProject from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html and then moving on to some other examples I've discovered over at https://rnplay.org/  .

Those simple projects all took the form of

- List React Imports
- Create classes with `var AwesomeProjectClassName = React.createClass({..`
- Sometimes there would be multiple classes, but there would be ONE overriding class that used other classes as content.
- Then at the bottom of the program there would be the lines :

  `module.exports = AwesomeProjectClassName;`
  `AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProjectClassName;`
- And things would run great, life is good.
- For a guide to understanding of module.exports line, check out [this link](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/).

I'm trying to move on to a more complex example. I don't understand how the final setup / start up works. The example I'm now looking at is the Webview tutorial, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html   The code is [also available at Github.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/WebViewExample.js)

Here's how the program should look on an iphone.

[image: Screen shot of iphone 1][image: Screen shot of iphone #2]

Here's an extract of the complete Webview Example.  This code is a bit more complex:

```
list react imports // obviously this is pseudo code...
var WebViewExample = React.createClass({...
var Button = React.createClass({...  // no problem here
var ScaledWebView = React.createClass({...
var styles = StyleSheet.create({... // no problem here
const HTML = `<!DOCTYPE html>\n ... // no problem here
```

And then I get:

```
exports.displayName = (undefined: ? string);
exports.title = '<WebView>';
exports.description = 'Base component to display web content';
exports.examples = [{
    title: 'Simple Browser',
    render(): ReactElement {
        return <WebViewExample / > ;
    }
}, {
    title: 'Scale Page to Fit',
    render(): ReactElement {
        return <ScaledWebView / > ;
    }
}, {
    title: 'Bundled HTML',
    render(): ReactElement {
        return ( < WebView style = {
                {
                    backgroundColor: BGWASH,
                    height: 100,
                }
            }
            source = {
                require('./helloworld.html')
            }
            scalesPageToFit = {
                true
            }
            />
        );
    }
}, {
    title: 'Static HTML',
    render(): ReactElement {
        return ( < WebView style = {
                {
                    backgroundColor: BGWASH,
                    height: 100,
                }
            }
            source = {
                {
                    html: HTML
                }
            }
            scalesPageToFit = {
                true
            }
            />
        );
    }
}, {
    title: 'POST Test',
    render(): ReactElement {
        return ( < WebView style = {
                {
                    backgroundColor: BGWASH,
                    height: 100,
                }
            }
            source = {
                {
                    uri: 'http://www.posttestserver.com/post.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: 'foo=bar&bar=foo'
                }
            }
            scalesPageToFit = {
                false
            }
            />
        );
    }
}];
```

I don't understand how to "send" this program to my ios emulator.  There is no single overriding class that controls things. It's not clear at all on how to register this stuff. Can anybody explain what I'm missing? How do you set

`module.exports = AwesomeProjectClassName;`
  `AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProjectClassName;`

for this example?  Can you explain exactly what's going on with:

```
exports.displayName = (undefined: ? string);
exports.title = '<WebView>';
exports.description = 'Base component to display web content';
exports.examples ...
```

I'm just not grasping the concepts here. I can see from stepping thru my code that `exports` is a simple object and that `exports.examples` is an array of objects.  Those objects contained in the array have a render function and a title, etc... What's not clear is how do I call that content so I get the sample output as shown in the images above.  This type of construction is peppered throughout the React Native examples, but no where can I find any details on how this stuff works.  Anybody have a clue?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/WebView/WebView.ios.js) is not an actual app. It's just a component. Look that the file is located at the `Libraries` folder and not the `Examples` in the repo. `UIExplorer` was created to demonstrate all of the components. You can find the `UIExplorer's` `AppRegistry.registerComponent`  [in this file](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/a80dd9a92a8d7c201972d1a8b2392e9f893147c8/Examples/UIExplorer/UIExplorerApp.ios.js) if you are curious. But it's more complex and built to allow using different components. `export` is used to make a variable/function/object available in other files. Try other examples from `Examples` folder, they are better for learning RN and use UIExplorer only to find out how to use a specific component.